# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hello friends have this problem,when I click the link shows me the error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

```
<a onclick='EditarMatricula();' class="btn blue btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Actualizar</a>
```

This is mi code edit.php

```
<?php
    include_once('../conexion.php');
    $idEdit = $_POST['idEdit'];
    $mat_edit = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT matricula.idmatricula, matricula.fecha, CONCAT(alumno.nombres,' ',alumno.apellidos) AS alumno, matricula.idalumno, periodo.nombre AS periodo, matricula.idperiodo, grado.nombre AS grado, matricula.idgrado, aula.nombre AS aula, matricula.idaula, matricula.tipo, matricula.turno FROM matricula INNER JOIN alumno ON matricula.idalumno = alumno.idalumno INNER JOIN periodo ON matricula.idperiodo = periodo.idperiodo INNER JOIN grado ON matricula.idgrado = grado.idgrado INNER JOIN aula ON matricula.idaula = aula.idaula WHERE matricula.idmatricula = $idEdit");
    $mat_edit->execute();
    $fila_matricula = $mat_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#alumno_edit").autocomplete({
            source: "autocompletar/buscaralunom.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#idalumno_edit').val(ui.item.idalumno);
            }
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#periodo_edit").autocomplete({
            source: "autocompletar/buscarpernom.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#idperiodo_edit').val(ui.item.idperiodo);
            }
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#grado_edit").autocomplete({
            source: "autocompletar/buscargranom.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#idgrado_edit').val(ui.item.idgrado);
            }
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#aula_edit").autocomplete({
            source: "autocompletar/buscaraulnom.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#idaula_edit').val(ui.item.idaula);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">EDITAR MATRÍCULA</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal well">
                <div>
                    <input name="ideditar" id="ideditar" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['idmatricula'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fecha:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <input name="fechamostrara_edit" id="fechamostrara_edit" class="form-control" required type="text" value="<?php print date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fila_matricula['fecha'])) ?>" readonly>
                        <input name="fecha_edit" id="fecha_edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['fecha'] ?>" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Alumno:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input name="alumno_edit" id="alumno_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['alumno'] ?>">
                        <input name="idalumno_edit" id="idalumno_edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['idalumno'] ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Periodo:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input name="periodo_edit" id="periodo_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['periodo'] ?>">
                        <input name="idperiodo_edit" id="idperiodo_edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['idperiodo'] ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Grado:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input name="grado_edit" id="grado_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['grado'] ?>">
                        <input name="idgrado_edit" id="idgrado_edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['idgrado'] ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Aula:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input name="aula_edit" id="aula_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['aula'] ?>">
                        <input name="idaula_edit" id="idaula_edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php print $fila_matricula['idaula'] ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="tipo_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Regular" <?php if ($fila_matricula['tipo'] == 'Regular') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Regular</span>
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="tipo_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Becado" <?php if ($fila_matricula['tipo'] == 'Becado') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Becado</span>
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="tipo_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Especial" <?php if ($fila_matricula['tipo'] == 'Especial') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Especial</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Turno:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="turno_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Mañana" <?php if ($fila_matricula['turno'] == 'Mañana') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Mañana</span>
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="turno_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Tarde" <?php if ($fila_matricula['turno'] == 'Tarde') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Tarde</span>
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label class="radio-linea">
                            <input type="radio" name="turno_edit" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_flat-blue" value="Noche" <?php if ($fila_matricula['turno'] == 'Noche') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > <span>Noche</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn dark btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Salir</a>
            <a onclick='EditarMatricula();' class="btn blue btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Actualizar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#fechamostrara_edit").datepicker({format: "dd-mm-yyyy", orientation:"bottom", autoclose: true});
        $("#fechamostrara_edit").change(function(event) {
            var fechamostrara_edit = $("#fechamostrara_edit").val();
            fechamostrara_edit = fechamostrara_edit.split("-").reverse().join("-");
            $("#fecha_edit").val(fechamostrara_edit);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is mat.js

```
function EditarMatricula(){
        var id = $("#ideditar").val();
        var fecha_edit = $("#fecha_edit").val();
        var idalumno_edit = $("#idalumno_edit").val();
        var idperiodo_edit = $("#idperiodo_edit").val();
        var idgrado_edit = $("#idgrado_edit").val();
        var idalula_edit = $("#idaula_edit").val();
        var tipo_edit = $("input[name='tipo_edit']:checked").val();
        var turno_edit = $("input[name='turno_edit']:checked").val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'class/matriculaeditar.php',
                data: {ideditar:id, fecha_edit:fecha_edit, idalumno_edit:idalumno_edit, idperiodo_edit:idperiodo_edit, idgrado_edit:idgrado_edit, idaula_edit:idaula_edit, tipo_edit:tipo_edit, turno_edit:turno_edit },//parametros
            success: function(data){
                    $(".mensajeeditar").hide();
                    $(".mensajeeditar").html("<div class='smseditar'> SE ACTUALIZO LOS DATOS <br> De la Matrícula</div>");
                        $('.mensajeeditar').fadeIn('slow');
            ListarMatriculas();
                }
        }).done(function() {
                $(".mensajeeditar").fadeOut( 4000, "linear");
                $("div").removeClass('modal-backdrop');
                $('#myModal-Edit').modal('hide');
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        });
} 

function ListarMatriculas(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'matricula_lista.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
            $("#miTabla").html(data);
            $("#miTabla").hide();
            $("#miTabla").fadeToggle('slow','linear');
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: "Maximum call stack exceeded" errors are usually the result of infinite [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Take a look at the stack trace and find what's causing the loop.

Comment: What happens in `ListarMatriculas()`, do you happen to make a call to `EditarMatricula()` or trigger the click event on your `a` element?

Comment: Hellow friend in function ListarMatriculas(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'matricula_lista.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
            $("#miTabla").html(data);
            $("#miTabla").hide();
            $("#miTabla").fadeToggle('slow','linear');
    }
  });
} Patrick Evans and As I view the stack trace any suggestions? mpen

Comment: As I view the stack trace any suggestions? @mpen

Comment: @JhoNerVega If you see A(), B(), C(), A(), B(), C(), ... in the stack that means A is calling B, and B is calling C and C is calling A. In such case you probably need an if() around one of those function calls, or the if() is wrong. It's hard to explain in words. One of those functions is being called when it shouldn't be. AKA, your "base case" is wrong. Assuming you even need recursion.

Comment: @mpen I understand a little but I found the solution anyway thank you very much I had to go every line of javascript until I found the error in one of the variables var idalula -----------> solucion var idaula :)